# drawRect's aRect argument in relation to UIView's bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, drawrect

I'm working on creating my first custom UIView and learning about the semantics of the drawRect method.

I have encountered [advice](http://parmanoir.com/CoreUI_can_paint_pretty_big) (advice that makes sense to me) to only draw within the scope of the `CGRect` that is passed in as an argument, rather than always drawing everything within the `UIView`'s `bounds`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)aRect {
    // draw, draw, draw...
}
```

What I'm trying to find out now is whether there are any constraints about what relationship there is between `bounds` and the `aRect` that gets passed in.   In particular, I'm wondering if `aRect` is guaranteed to be entirely inside `bounds`, or whether it may extends outside of `bounds`.

If some code outside of my `UIView` passes, for example, a very large CGRect into `setNeedsDisplayInRect:(NSRect)invalidRect`, will the underlying code just blindly pass the same CGRect into my `drawRect` method, or does it do some sort of intersection and always pass in a sensible rectangle?

I haven't found an answer to this in any documentation.  Is this something I shouldn't even worry about?  Or should I always intersect `bounds` and `aRect` on my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW3):

> Before calling your view’s drawRect: method, UIKit configures the basic drawing environment for your view. Specifically, it creates a graphics context and adjusts the coordinate system and clipping region to match the coordinate system and visible bounds of your view.

You won't be asked to draw outside your view. Even if you were, the clip rect should be set such that the drawing would have no effect.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit that I even recognize having read that passage before.  Thank you!